# XCode stackview adding elements

Tags: ios, xcode, uikit, uistackview

Im very new to xcode so bear with me. I added a vertical Stackview and want to add a bunch of textviews and buttons starting from the top. I managed to use constrains to stretch the Stackview to the screen on all sides.

Now when I add 3 textviews this happens, and its all wrong: first the textviews stick to the bottom for some reason, second one stretches out the remaining space which is obviously wrong. What can I do to make it correct, i.e. all textviews should be at top right under each other with correct width and height (width fills the screen, height is whatever the default height is)

[image]

Comment: Remove the Bottom constraint from your Stackview...

Answer (score 0):

A `UIStackView` will *arrange* its subviews.

If you set a Height - either explicitly or by constraints on the Top and Bottom, the stack view will *arrange* the subviews to fit into that height - when set to Fill or Fill Equally, it will "spread out and resize" the subviews.

If you ***don't*** constrain its Height, it will still *arrange* its subviews, but it will expand its *own* height based on the heights of the subviews.

So, for your case of 3 text fields, constraining all 4 sides results in the subviews being arranged to fit the height of the stack view.

If you constrain the stack view only to Top, Left and Right, you get this (main view is blue, stack view has spacing set to 8):

[image]